# Display two databases table content in parallel with HTML table tag

Tags: php, html-table

I am  trying to display a list of new notifications by truncate the first 20 chars of the new notification and put it in `<a></a>` so if user want to read the whole thing he can click the hypered link and continue reading.

There is two type of notifications (which I'm trying to print an HTML table first column for one notification type and second column for the other type) the two types are (monthly evaluation feedback & general exam feedback)

And here's what I've done:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM msgs WHERE stdID='".$id."' AND opened='0'";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
$data = mysql_fetch_array($query);
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM exam WHERE stdID='".$id."' AND evaluated='1'";
$query2 = mysql_query($sql2);
$data2 = mysql_fetch_array($query2);

if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0 || mysql_num_rows($query2) > 0)
{   echo '<table border="1"><tr><th width="10%" align="right" style="margin-right:200%;"></th><th width="20%" align="right" style="padding-bottom:20px">Monthly Evaluation Feedback</th><th width="20%" align="right" style="padding-bottom:20px">General Exam Feedback</th></tr>';
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($query) || $row2 = mysql_fetch_row($query2))
    {
        if($row2 = mysql_fetch_row($query2))
        {   echo '<tr><td width="10%" align="right"></td>';
            echo '<td width="20%" align="right"><span class="toggle" style="padding:3px;"><a id="hline'.$row[0].'" style="cursor:pointer;" onClick="markAsRead('.$row[0].')"/>- '.stripslashes(substr($row[1],0,20)).'</a></span></td>';
            echo '<td width="20%" align="right"><span class="toggle" style="padding:3px;"><a id="hline'.$row2[0].'" style="cursor:pointer;" onClick="markAsRead('.$row2[0].')"/>- '.stripslashes(substr($row2[2],0,20)).'</a></span></td></tr>'; //This line wont print the truncated msg (substr($row2[2],0,20)).
        } else {
            echo '<tr><td width="10%" align="right"></td>';
            echo '<td width="20%" align="right"><span class="toggle" style="padding:3px;"><a id="hline'.$row[0].'" style="cursor:pointer;" onClick="markAsRead('.$row[0].')"/>- '.stripslashes(substr($row[1],0,20)).'</a></span></td></tr>'; //And this line wont print the truncated msg (substr($row[2],0,20)).
        }
    } echo '</table>';
}
else {echo 'there is no new notification';}
?>
```

It works fine but as I've mentioned in the code `stripslashes(substr($row[1],0,20))` will not display the first 20 cars of the feedback !
and I did it this way (if statement inside the loop) to avoid that `$row2` being undefined because `$row` always greater that `$row2`

Comment: A side note: 2014 is coming in less than 100 hours! Don't use [the obsoleted `mysql_*` extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) any more, use [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) instead, and [variable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) [binding](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) technique...

Comment: thank you, I will do some searches about MySQLi and PDO.

Comment: it didn't do the magic, the same error appers

Comment: That's why I said it's a "side note". And to your question, 1) `stripslashes` is not a valid way to sanitize HTML output; 2) `var_dump($row)` and `var_dump($row2)` to see what's going on. The eye-catching problem I see is the possible-double-fetching of `$query2` and `$row` possibly being `false`.